Ошибка интернет магазина open cart3
Недавно крашнулся магазин на opencart. Появляется вот такая ошибка:
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'a324455_1'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) in /home/httpd/vhosts/xn--80aatg4adpbhlk5a.xn--p1ai/httpdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/httpd/vhosts/xn--80aatg4adpbhlk5a.xn--p1ai/httpdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/httpd/vhosts/xn--80aatg4adpbhlk5a.xn--p1ai/httpdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
Самой разобраться не могу,  буду рада помощи.
Обращалась в тех поддержку, там написали что не могут решить проблему, заблокировали базу данных:
Вынуждены заблокировать базу данных a324455_1, так как ее работа производит нагрузку на сервер, это препятствует нормальной работе других сайтов, а также может привести к сбою сам сервер.
| 622524211 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16164 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM p9593_category_path cp LEFT JOIN p9593_product_to_ | 0 | 0 |
| 622524212 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16166 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM p9593_category_path cp LEFT JOIN p9593_product_to_ | 0 | 0 |
| 622524216 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16186 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM p9593_category_path cp LEFT JOIN p9593_product_to_ | 0 | 0 |
| 622524235 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16276 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM p9593_category_path cp LEFT JOIN p9593_product_to_ | 0 | 0 |
| 622524245 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16314 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM p9593_category_path cp LEFT JOIN p9593_product_to_ | 0 | 0 |
| 622524252 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16358 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM p9593_category_path cp LEFT JOIN p9593_product_to_ | 0 | 0 |
| 622524258 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16380 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM p9593_category_path cp LEFT JOIN p9593_product_to_ | 0 | 0 |
| 622524269 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16440 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM p9593_category_path cp LEFT JOIN p9593_product_to_ | 0 | 0 |
| 622524281 | a324455_1 | 127.0.0.1:16482 | a324455_1 | Query | 0 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE p9593_product SET viewed = (viewed + 1) WHERE product_id = '362'

Переезжайте на VPS или разбирайтесь с запросами, которые создают большую нагрузку на БД.
